# html5 animation with help of js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do html5 `animation` please refer the following diagram.
on left side I have a menu list and on right side i have an image as shown in figure.
on click of the 1 link the image which I shown as blue oval will move down diagonally  as shown in image2 and then open one div for example square at center of right div ok.
Next on click on 2 link the square div will hide and the oval image comes to its original position and again animate to the diagonal botton and open another div for example this time image
[image]
[image]

i had already achieve some animation but not upto the end.
if any more description needed tell me....

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salwenikhil0724/wZKzb/)

Comment: Post that "already achieved animation" code..

Comment: hie Joke just look at the demo.i because some reason i remove somethng from code but still its working kindly go through it..

Comment: can u look at the Demo?

Comment: ya one link one is working i am stuck with 2nd navigation onclick on 1st link image animate as i want and div is also displayed but on click of 2nd link i want this same image animate to its original position and again animate to as same on click on 1st and then show another div.

Comment: has anybody got answer..